# Catch Windows 8.1 system events/triggers with PowerShhell 4.0 using Register-WmiEvent?

Tags: windows, events, powershell, wmi, powershell-4.0

I am trying to write an **efficient** Windows 8.1 PowerShell 4.0 script that will catch/trigger on two types of events. I want to be able to catch these events/triggers so I can do something like run a script or start/stop a service or something.

The events I want to catch/trigger on are:

- power cable plugged/unplugged (battery charging/discharging)
- hardware (like the Surface Pro 2 Type Cover 2) is connected/disconnected

By efficient I mean the script ***shouldn't*** have an infinite loop to periodically check the status. I would assume I should be able to write something that will catch events as Windows generates them?

So far I have learned that I can use the [`Register-WmiEvent`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849840.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet to subscribe to WMI events.

1. I assume this is the most efficient way of doing it so I don't have to continuously poll and instead react to an event?
2. And if so, is it better to use `-query` or `-class` when registering for events? The only difference I have seen is that it's obviously easy to filter on events when using `-query` (e.g. `Register-WmiEvent -query "Select * From Win32_PowerManagementEvent where EventType=10"`).

I'll worry about how to catch the specific events I need later. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to catch/trigger events in general.

Comment: Why are you targeting a "Windows 8.1 Powershell 2.0 script"? 8.1 shipped with PowerShell v4.

Comment: @alroc: Oops! Thanks! I thought it was 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one (power cable plugged/unplugged), have a look to [Win32_PowerManagementEvent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ; you can use :

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query "select * from Win32_PowerManagementEvent" -MessageData "Event Power by JPB" -SourceIdentifier "EVTPOW1" 
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "EVTPOW1"
```

Or

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query "select * from Win32_PowerManagementEvent"  -SourceIdentifier "EVTPOW2"  -Action {Write-Host "blurp"; [console]::Beep(500,500)}
```

In the second case you put in your script block the code you need.

Comment: Woops! Yes. Sorry. Thank you!

Comment: How do you actual see the details of the triggering event  - so you could (for instance) distuingish between power-on/power-off ?